# Outer form updated details, but the nested form did not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Apologies if the answer to this is obvious, but I'm only a month and a half into Rails.

Basically, I have an edit restaurant form.

```
= simple_form_for(restaurant, html: { class: 'session_form with_padding' }) do |f|
  %h3
    %b
      Manager Details
  = simple_fields_for :promoter do |p|
    .row
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-6
        = p.label :first_name, required: false, class: 'control-label'
        .form-group{:class => ('has-error' if restaurant.errors[:manager_first_name].first)}
          = p.text_field :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', value: restaurant.promoter.first_name
          %h5
            = p.full_error :first_name
    .row
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-6
        = p.label :last_name, required: false, class: 'control-label'
        .form-group{:class => ('has-error' if restaurant.errors[:manager_last_name].first)}
          = p.text_field :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', value: restaurant.promoter.last_name
          %h5
            = p.full_error :last_name
  %h3
    %b
      Restaurant Details
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-6
      = f.label :name, required: false, class: 'control-label'
      .form-group{:class => ('has-error' if restaurant.errors[:name].first)}
        = f.text_field :name, required: true, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'
        %h5
          = f.full_error :name
      = f.label :address, required: false, class: 'control-label'
      .form-group{:class => ('has-error' if restaurant.errors[:address].first)}
        %input#pac-input.controls{:placeholder => "Search address", :type => "text", class: 'form-control'}
        %h5
          = f.full_error :address
```

Inside of the form, I have a nested form for the 'Manager Details'. What I've been trying to achieve here is to save the details when they're updated. I edit a "Restaurant Details" and a "Manager Details" field and then hit the submit button, but in the terminal, I can only see an SQL update to a column in the restaurants, but no updates to a Promoter column.

Also, I have two models, Promoter and Restaurant. Promoter has_many restaurants and Restaurant belongs_to promoter.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :promoter
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :promoter
  ...
end

class Promoter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurants
  ...
end
```

Here's the restaurant's controller.

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_restaurant, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_promoter!

  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
    @restaurant.update(promoter_id: current_promoter.id)

    if @restaurant.save
      return render :crop if logo_exists?
      redirect_to restaurant_path(@restaurant)
      flash[:notice] = 'Restaurant was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @restaurant.update(restaurant_params)
      return render :crop if logo_exists?
      redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def set_restaurant
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
  end

  def restaurant_params
    return permitted_params unless permitted_params[:phone_number].present?
    parameters = permitted_params
    parameters[:phone_number] =
      "+#{params[:country_code]}#{parameters[:phone_number]}"
    parameters
  end

  def permitted_params
    params
      .require(:restaurant)
      .permit(:name, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :phone_number,
              :manager_first_name, :website, :manager_last_name,
              :manager_email, :manager_phone_number, :logo, :logo_cache,
              :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h, :service_charge, :gst,
              :first_name, :last_name, :email,
              operating_hours_attributes: [:id, :day, :opening_time,
              :closing_time, :enabled, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

Promoter's controller

```
class Promoters::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  after_action :subscribe_mailchimp, only: :create, if: '@promoter.persisted?'

  def create
    @promoter = Promoter.new(promoter_params)
    if @promoter.save
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      redirect_to restaurants_path, notice:
      'Welcome! You have signed up successfully'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def promoter_params
    parameters = permitted_params
    parameters[:phone_number] =
      "+#{params[:country_code]}#{parameters[:phone_number]}"
    parameters
  end

  def permitted_params
    params
      .require(:promoter)
      .permit(
        :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number,
        :password, :password_confirmation, :country_code,
        :terms)
  end
end
```

The code pasted here are the ones I believe is necessary. Soz if it's too long.

My question is, why doesn't the fields_for :promotion update the data in the database? I'll add my routes file once I can.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is on these line

```
= simple_fields_for :promoter do |p|
```

replace with these:

```
= f.fields_for :promoter do |p|
```

Comment: Tried this as well, but redirected me back to the edit page but the URL isn't saying /edit/. No updates to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the receiver for `simple_fields_for` to associate the promoter fields with the larger form.

Instead of

```
  = simple_fields_for :promoter do |p|
```

Do

```
  = f.simple_fields_for :promoter do |p|
```

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't place the f before simple_fields_for. But unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem.